# BigQuery or SQL Server SPLIT query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, google-bigquery

I have searched around and can not find much on this topic. I have a table, that gets logging information. As a result the column I am interested in contains multiple values that I need to search against. The column is formatted in a php URL style. i.e.

```
/test/test.aspx?DS_Vendor=55039&DS_ProdVer=7.90.100.0&DS_ProdLang=EN&DS_Product=MTT&DS_OfficeBits=32
```

This makes all searches end up with really long regexes to get data. Then join statements to combine data.

Is there a way in BigQuery, or SQL Server that I can pull the information from that column and put it into new columns?

**Example:**

[image: Example]

The information I would like extracted begins after the ?, and ends at &, The string can sometimes be longer, and contains additional headers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and addresses below aspect of your question

> Is there a way in BigQuery, ... that I can pull the information from that column and put it into new columns?

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION parseColumn(kv STRING, column_name STRING) AS (
  IF(SPLIT(kv, '=')[OFFSET(0)]= column_name, SPLIT(kv, '=')[OFFSET(1)], NULL)
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '/test/test.aspx?extra=abc&DS_Vendor=55039&DS_ProdVer=7.90.100.0&DS_ProdLang=EN&DS_Product=MTT&DS_OfficeBits=32' AS url UNION ALL 
  SELECT '/test/test.aspx?DS_Vendor=55192&DS_ProdVer=4.30.100.0&more=123&DS_ProdLang=DE&DS_Product=MTE&DS_OfficeBits=64' 
)
SELECT
  MIN(parseColumn(kv, 'DS_Vendor'))     AS DS_Vendor,
  MIN(parseColumn(kv, 'DS_ProdVer'))    AS DS_ProdVer,
  MIN(parseColumn(kv, 'DS_ProdLang'))   AS DS_ProdLang,
  MIN(parseColumn(kv, 'DS_Product'))    AS DS_Product,
  MIN(parseColumn(kv, 'DS_OfficeBits')) AS DS_OfficeBits
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r'[?&]([^?&]+)')) AS kv
GROUP BY url
```

with the result as below

```sql
Row DS_Vendor   DS_ProdVer  DS_ProdLang DS_Product  DS_OfficeBits    
1   55039       7.90.100.0  EN          MTT         32   
2   55192       4.30.100.0  DE          MTE         64
```

Below is also addressed

> The string can sometimes be longer, and contains additional headers.

Comment: Ah, I should have clicked the image (before the edit). While my answer may be useful, this addresses the question better.

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need, but I need to be able to pull multiple columns from the table. For example the Column name is Loginfo, and I want to pull every row for that column.

Comment: usually answer as good as question is! you can ask new question and provide more details. the current question as it is asked is answered I think :o)

Answer (score 2):

One example using BigQuery (with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/)):

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r'[?&]([^?&]+)')
FROM (
  SELECT '/test/test.aspx?DS_Vendor=55039&DS_ProdVer=7.90.100.0&DS_ProdLang=EN&DS_Product=MTT&DS_OfficeBits=32' AS url
)
```

This returns the parts of the URL as an `ARRAY<STRING>`. To go one step further, you can get back an `ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>` with a query of this form:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      SPLIT(part, '=')[OFFSET(0)] AS key,
      SPLIT(part, '=')[OFFSET(1)] AS value
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r'[?&]([^?&]+)')) AS part
  ) AS keys_and_values
FROM (
  SELECT '/test/test.aspx?DS_Vendor=55039&DS_ProdVer=7.90.100.0&DS_ProdLang=EN&DS_Product=MTT&DS_OfficeBits=32' AS url
)
```

...or with the keys and values as top-level columns:

```
SELECT
  SPLIT(part, '=')[OFFSET(0)] AS key,
  SPLIT(part, '=')[OFFSET(1)] AS value
FROM (
  SELECT '/test/test.aspx?DS_Vendor=55039&DS_ProdVer=7.90.100.0&DS_ProdLang=EN&DS_Product=MTT&DS_OfficeBits=32' AS url
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r'[?&]([^?&]+)')) AS part
```